# websphere application server calling the redirect causes creation of new session

Tags: redirect, websphere, session-cookies

I am deploying a jsf app on websphere application server 8.5.5.16 but calling the responce.sendRedirect() causes creation of a new session.

Has anyone have such case? or can help me to figure out what is going on?

Comment: This method is not jsf related but pure servlet. Start by reading [ask] then [mcve] then investigate network traffic, cookies, urls etc... start by approaching this as  a developer

Comment: Actually it turns out to be an Websphere  session settings . 
So all what you really needed to know is  there .

Comment: Grwat you solved it, but what I meeded to know? I'm here with  jsf knowledge, not websphere. Wrong tagging leads to others reading question (costing time) with which they can't help. If that happens a lot (and it does) they could stop helping. Which nobody likes, so creating good questions wirh good tagging and enough investigation upfront is paramount

Answer (score 0):

We figured this out, it was websphere settings and https related.
Go to :

Application servers > server > Session management > Cookies
Check "Restrict cookies to HTTPS sessions" .